# Dividends paid on stocks bought on Bursa Malaysia

Tags: taxes, stocks, malaysia

Are dividends paid on stocks bought on Bursa, Malaysia taxable?

Comment: What country/countries do you live in/pay taxes in?

Answer (score 1):

Post 2008, the companies registered in Malaysia are required to deduct the taxes on dividends and then distribute it to shareholders. The dividend received in the hands of shareholder is tax free.